# Swiffy-created drag and drop stopped working on iPad after update

Tags: drag-and-drop, google-swiffy

I think swiffy's runtime updated recently and made my drag and drop animations stop working in iPad.

The code for my application (in Flash) basically uses a MOUSE_DOWN handler to start the animation, then the object on the screen follows mouse.x and mouse.y, and stops following on the MOUSE_UP handler. I'll try to include some relevant code to give the idea.

```
var movetimer:Timer = new Timer(20, 0); // movement timer
movetimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onmovetimer);

function onmovetimer(evt:TimerEvent):void {
    if (isDragged !== null) {
        //trace('following mouse, '+isDragged.x+' and '+isDragged.y);
        isDragged.x = mouseX - xAdj;    
        isDragged.y = mouseY - yAdj;
    } else {
        movetimer.stop();
        //trace('timer stopped');
    }
}

function dragHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    isDragged = event.target as MovieClip;
    xAdj = mouseX - isDragged.x;
    yAdj = mouseY - isDragged.y;
    movetimer.start();
    }
```

This got converted to swiffy and was working okay on iPad and Android tablets before last week.

Then, last week, I tested on iPad and realized it no longer worked there (still works in Android).

My theory is that a recent update to the runtime, the update from 6.0.1 to 6.0.2 or the update from 6.0.0 to 6.0.1, discontinued support for whatever feature made MOUSE_DOWN and MOUSE_UP work that way when converted. Of course I can't figure out exactly what's going on - the swiffy code is a black box so far as I'm concerned and I don't have a good testing routine on the tablet. All I can tell is that nothing happens on drag on the iPad, while stuff continues to happen on drag for the Android.

So I need the following... either an archived version of the swiffy runtime, or another approach.

I've been thinking about using touchstart and touchend in my code. However when I compile that in Flash it doesn't work (Flash doesn't recognize that code and won't compile).

I tried to install the swiffy extension but it doesn't seem to work with Flash CC, or at least Adobe Extension Manager refuses to recognize it.

I can't seem to find any place that archives the swiffy runtime, or for that matter, an organized way to contact google for that application (I've done feedback on it but they say on the form they won't do individual responses...)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: So I followed advice from someone on the Google groups forums and set my files to use the latest script available before this one, 5.4 (I had been using 6.0, which was silently updated to 6.0.1, and that was what broke my code). Anyway reverting to the old code seems to have fixed my problem - I'll continue testing but I'm probably going with this solution. It's a pity, I would have rather used a more comprehensive / responsible solution than simply reverting to old code.